# After starting hadoop, i cannot start mahout ..!

Tags: mahout

**When Starting Mahout i got an error message like this**

> root@fazil-VPCEB45FG:/usr/local/mahout/bin# ./mahout
>
> hadoop binary is not in PATH,HADOOP_HOME/bin,HADOOP_PREFIX/bin, running locally
>
> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> Could not reserve enough space for object heap
>
> Could not create the Java virtual machine.

**i have installed openjdk0.6, Whether openjdk is supported by mahout**

Comment: -1 little info, poorly formatted, unclear question.

Answer (score 1):

There's no OpenJDK 0.6 -- you mean 1.6. Yes Java 6 is supported, as you see in the project documentation. This does not seem to have anything to do with Mahout as it's an error from the JVM itself. The error itself says the problem: you requested a heap that's too large. So, I'd go see what heap you requested in Hadoop config and check it. This is the kind of info you should post in a question.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly what is says in the error message

> Could not reserve enough space for object heap

check your your hadoop config files: `hadoop-env.sh` and 
`mapred-site.xml` for any properties where you have allocated memory to JVM through the `Xmx` parameter and lower the values if you don't have enough physical memory.
If you have plenty of ram and you run java on 64-bit OS you need to add a `-d64` java option to enforce 64-bit mode (it's not done by default in some cases)

Edit: for stand alone mode (your case) just use a proper Xmx value and -d64 if it is 64bits OS

Answer (score 0):

JAVA_HEAP_MAX parameter in mahout file you're running should be lowered. It was 3GB in the mahout version I downloaded.